# How can I connect a user model to a custom model in Django?

Tags: django

I have a student model with a one-to-one relationship to the built-in Django User model. My aim is to combine both forms in a single template for registration such that whenever I create a new student, the student object is automatically assigned a user by using Django post_save signals.
Below are the code snippets:

1. models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Student(models.Model):
  CURRENT_CLASS = (
    ('1', 'Form 1'),
    ('2', 'Form 2'),
    ('3', 'Form 3'),
    ('4', 'Form 4'),
  )
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  adm_num = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  form = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CURRENT_CLASS, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

2. forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from .models import Student

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']

class StudentForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['user']
```

3. views.py

```
def signupPage(request):
  form = CreateUserForm()
  student_form = StudentForm()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    student_form =StudentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and student_form.is_valid():
      user = form.save()
      username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
      messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)
      return redirect('student:login')
    else:
      form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
  context = {
    'form': form,
    'student_form': student_form,
  }
  return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', context)
```

4. signup.html

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}
    <br>
  {% endfor %}
  {% for field in student_form %}
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}
    <br>
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" value="Register Student">
</form>
{{  form.errors}}
<span>Already have an account?</span>
<a href="{% url 'student:login' %}">Login</a>
```

Comment: The best instructions I've seen about the different ways to extend the user model are here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html . Click though to this link for instructions on the way that you have chosen: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone

Answer (score 0):

Update your view to also save the student like:

```
if form.is_valid() and student_form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()
    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    student_obj = Student.objects.create(
        user=user,
        first_name=student_form.cleaned_data.get('first_name'),
        last_name=student_form.cleaned_data.get('last_name'),
        adm_num=student_form.cleaned_data.get('adm_num'),
        form=student_form.cleaned_data.get('form')
    )
    messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)
    return redirect('student:login')
```

Comment: Has been of great help, although I had to change the relationship to Foreign Key in order for it to work, but if there's a way it can work with OneToOne field I'll be very grateful. Much appreciation.